# Adding a 'While' Loop To My Program

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm working on a program that calculates the area of either a circle (C), square (S), or rectangle (R), depending on what letter the user inputs. I've tested it and it works fine; the code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestLoops {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your shape? Enter C for circle, S for " + 
            "square, R for rectangle, or X to exit: ");
    String Shape = input.nextLine();

    if (Shape.equals("C")) {
        System.out.println("What is your circle's radius?: ");
        double Radius = input.nextDouble();
        double cFormula = (3.14 * Radius * Radius);
        System.out.println("Your circle's area = " + cFormula); 
    }
    else if (Shape.equals("S")) {
        System.out.println("What is the length of your shape's sides?: ");
        double Side = input.nextDouble();
        double sFormula = (Side * Side);
        System.out.println("Your square's area = " + sFormula);           
    }
    else if (Shape.equals("R")) {
        System.out.println("What is your rectangle's height?: ");
        double Height = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is your rectangle's width?: ");
        double Width = input.nextDouble();
        double rFormula = (Height * Width);
        System.out.println("Your rectangle's area = " + rFormula);
    }

   }

  }
```

Now, what I want to do is add a loop to the program. For example, if the user inputs C for circle and puts in the number 22 for the radius, they'll get an answer, but I want the program to loop back to the beginning again so that it asks the user "What is your shape?...". Also, if the user types in X instead of C, S, or R, I want the program to quit, but I'm not sure how to add that in, either.

I know that I need to add a 'while' loop, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, because I don't know *where* to insert that part of the code. Do I add the 'while' loop somewhere at the beginning of the code, after the last "if else" statement, or... Also, I'm not actually sure *what* to type. Should it be something like,

```
while (Shape == C, S, R) {
   ....?
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated by any one in the coding community! I will continue to work on this code on my own as well.

Comment: Two things. If you want the user to be asked again after a successful shape process is done, you put everything in a loop. If you want to validate input, you put another loop inside and make it run while input is not c or s or r. Unfortunately I can give examples in Python only (or pseudo code)

Comment: a good start would be to identify the lines in your existing code that shall be repeated and put them into a method of their own and call that from `main`. In the second step you can wrap that single line in in main calling that new method  with the loop.

Comment: `while (Arrays.asList("C", "S", "R").contains(Shape))`. You can build `Arrays.asList("C", "S", "R")` once, and reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the `do, while`

So, the program will always do something while the conditions that are set are being accomplished, so you want your program to look something like:

```
public class TestLoops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean thisB = false; /*this is the guy who will tell the loop to stop the execution when the user inserts X*/
        String shape;
        do{
            System.out.println("What is your shape? Enter C for circle, S for " +
                    "square, R for rectangle, or X to exit: ");
            shape = input.next();

            if(shape.equalsIgnoreCase("C") || shape.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || shape.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                if (shape.equals("C")) {
                    System.out.println("What is your circle's radius?: ");
                    double Radius = input.nextDouble();
                    double cFormula = (3.14 * Radius * Radius);
                    System.out.println("Your circle's area = " + cFormula);
                } else if (shape.equals("S")) {
                    System.out.println("What is the length of your shape's sides?: ");
                    double Side = input.nextDouble();
                    double sFormula = (Side * Side);
                    System.out.println("Your square's area = " + sFormula);
                } else if (shape.equals("R")) {
                    System.out.println("What is your rectangle's height?: ");
                    double Height = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("What is your rectangle's width?: ");
                    double Width = input.nextDouble();
                    double rFormula = (Height * Width);
                    System.out.println("Your rectangle's area = " + rFormula);
                }
            }
            else if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) thisB = true;/*or in other words: stop*/
        }
        while(!thisB);
    }

}
```

Things to consider:

1) Naming conventions, always start variable names with undercase using `camelCase`, in your example `shape` started with UpperCase

2) When in a `while` loop, use only `next()`, not `nextLine()` to pick up the values as the latter will duplicate the question in the `System.out.Println`.

3) The optimum way to do this is to put all your `if` clauses in a method and call it with the parameter from the `Scanner` input.  Even better would be having a method per shape, as things can get hairy depending on requests

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I find that it made the most sense of all the answers because it was closest to the level of coding I'm doing at the moment. I would like to ask, what does thisB mean, however? I'm guessing that the name you're chosen for the boolean variable?

Comment: Yes, that was just me being lazy, it's short for thisBoolean, but you should call it control or something that makes sense.
  Glad I could help, if you believe the answer fit, please upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Will do! I'm going to be adjusting my code and changing a few things like the point you made about changing variables to lowercase letters. I don't mean to eat up too much of your time, but would it be all right with you if I shoot you another question or two if I run into an issue? I feel like I'm on the cusp of where I need to be and I appreciate how you've cleared up somethings I've been wondering about.

Comment: Sure! Fire any question, I might fall asleep in not too long as it's pretty late uk time, but while awake I will try to help

Comment: I've been looking over the code/testing it and it works like a dream. I have no questions, so my next step is to just study the steps you've added in so I can understand them for use next time. My textbook and instructor also mentioned Booleans during our lectures, so I appreciate you using familiar beginner concepts. You're awesome and I appreciate your time, help, and patience!

Comment: Great! Happy coding now! :)